# Enum field in JPA Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums

I feel a little dumb asking this but I can't find any simple answer to the question.

Take this simple entity as example:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="clienti" )
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String cognome;

//...
}
```

It represents a person, so I want to add a "**gender**" property.

It will be "male" or "female". So what?

I can use a String, and keep in mind that "m" stands for male and "f" for female.

Or I can use a boolean "isMale", true or false.

However, I don't think in either case Hibernate purists would be happy :)

Googling a little bit I found that the best practice is using an **enum**.

I am a little confused on how to use it. Can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can map your `enum` to a `String` or to an ordinal number. Mapping to `String` is the more portable approach as the mapping will survive changing the enumeration order.

Using your example:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="clienti" )
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

...
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
...
}
```

The string mapping will use the simple name of the enumeration type, so you would have two possible values in the DB - 'Male' and 'Female'

```
public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE }
```

The persistence provider takes care of the mapping, so in your code, you can continue using the `Gender` enum and not worry about Strings or ordinals.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm just gonna try before accepting your answer. Only one thing... "Gender" enum has to be in its own file doesn't it?

Comment: @FabioB. - it can also be an inner class if you want to expose the gender only to the client objects, but in general I would advise to define it as a top-level enum.

Comment: You should also consider using `EnumType.ORDINAL` instead, if you plan to change the value name in the future.

Comment: EnumType.ORDINAL is a very bad idea. If you accidentally add or remove an ENUM from between and not the end, it will corrupt  your outputs as ORDINAL uses logical order in which enums are declared. Avoid it.

Comment: It is actually quite a bad idea to use enum for gender: The maximum amount of possible fields are 65536.

Answer (score 6):

```
public enum Gender{ 
    MALE, FEMALE 
}



@Entity
@Table( name="clienti" )
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
...

// **1 case** - If database column type is number (integer) 
// (some time for better search performance)  -> we should use 
// EnumType.ORDINAL as @O.Badr noticed. e.g. inserted number will
// index of constant starting from 0... in our example for MALE - 0, FEMALE - 1.
// **Possible issue (advice)**: you have to add the new values at the end of
// your enum, in order to keep the ordinal correct for future values.

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Gender gender;


// **2 case** - If database column type is character (varchar) 
// and you want to save it as String constant then ->

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

...
}

// in all case on code level you will interact with defined 
// type of Enum constant but in Database level
```

*first case (EnumType.ORDINAL)*

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME      ║ GENDER ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║    0   ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║    0   ║
║  3 ║Jarrod Jesica ║    1   ║
║  4 ║ Joel Lucy    ║    1   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

*second case (EnumType.STRING)*

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME      ║ GENDER ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║  MALE  ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  MALE  ║
║  3 ║Jarrod Jesica ║ FEMALE ║
║  4 ║ Joel Lucy    ║ FEMALE ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: If you choose a string type and want the output in lower case, can that be accomplished? how so using @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)?