# how to generate tables from enums with values in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

```
@Entity
public class User{

  @Id()
  private int id;

  private UserStatus userStatus;
}

public enum Country{
    Active, Pending, Blocked;
}
```

I want to create a UserStatus Table with the values inside.

1st approach would be to use  @Enumerated with String or Integer.but, i dont want that, since these enum values can be changed.

Another approach is to have declare @Entity on the UserStatus class. add Id and value. Keep a ManyToOne mapping . so that, user will have the referenced foreign key as the userstatus.

Is it the best approach, if we want to persist the enum values in the table or is there any other approach ?
Can we generate the Gender table with enum values in it in spring boot?

[ The UserStatus enum is just an example. The main idea is to know what are the best approaches to create the table and it's value.]

I would be very glad to have some points around this.

Comment: A Gender table? Really?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enum field in JPA Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437384/enum-field-in-jpa-entity)

Comment: if we use @Enumerated.Ordinal/String, then it will save the corresponding value to the column. But thats not the best approach.

Comment: i have updated the question for more clarification

Comment: @Pino, a gender table is useful when you need to map gender to pronoun and article for when the language does change them by gender. It helps building more natural looking texts. If a new gender pops up, you just need to change one place and start using it without changing the code at all. You could even let people decide what gender / article / pronoun they want with a table like this and have an algorithm decide after x amount of data new factual genders and improve the default choices being shown (kind of like how ReCaptcha used to help digitizing books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you are using `MySQL` as Database.

Now if I ask you

**How will you store Country column in User table?**

**What will be Column type?**

`VARCHAR` I guess.

Same approach is followed in `@Entity` level as well.

So this approachs sounds good to me

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserStatus gender;
```

Can read this post for [more detail](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Regarding your suggestion on

> @Entity on the UserStatus

You are adding 1 more layer of complexity.

Will have to manage another Table. `LAZY_LODAING, CASCADING` and other stuff need to be handled.